# How to return a list of counts of even numbers in each of the inner lists in values? I don't know what part of my code is wrong

Tags: python

```
def count_evens(values: List[List[int]]) -> List[int]:
    """Return a list of counts of even numbers in each of the inner lists
    of values. 
    
    >>> count_evens([[10, 20, 30]])
    [3]
    >>> count_evens([[1, 2], [3], [4, 5, 6]])
    [1, 0, 2]
    """
    new_list = []
    count = 0
    
    for sublist in values:
        for i in sublist:
            if i % 2 == 0:
                count += 1
            else:
                count += 0
    new_list.append(count)
    return new_list
```

Comment: "I don't know what part of my code is wrong" Well, how do you know it is wrong, in the first place? Did you get the wrong result? Did it show an error?

Comment: you're not resetting `count` between loops and your call to `append` the `count` variable is outside the loop completely

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and think about your logic more carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate fix is the following:

```
new_list = []
for sublist in values:
    count = 0
    for i in sublist:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            count += 1
    new_list.append(count)
return new_list
```

Note the two lines that have moved into the loop.
Also, you can shorten this dramatically:

```
return [sum(i % 2 == 0 for i in lst) for lst in values]
```

Or even this, if you are a friend of bit operations:

```
return [sum(~i & 1 for i in lst) for lst in values]
```